# Spool documents printed from OPOS Driver

Tags: c#, python, thermal-printer, pos, opos

I want to intercept the documents printed through OPOS driver. I have successfully intercepted data with windows printer but not able to intercept OPOS. Is there anyway to create spool file of OPOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spool function is not defined in the OPOS specification.

Also, the function to monitor or hook the print contents is not defined.

Even if there is an OPOS control with such features, it will be specific to a particular vendor.

Please ask the printer vendor you are using for such features.

Alternatively, data can be obtained by hardware such as a line monitor such as USB or serial, but it is for investigations when problems occur and it is not practical to use it at store operation.

Comment: So is there anyway you can intercept the data or tap into the print queue of OPOS?

Comment: There is no such way unless individual vendors implement their own specifications that are not specified in OPOS.